# Installing Xcode documentation

Tags: audiokit

At the bottom of the [AudioKit Downloads page](http://audiokit.io/downloads/) there is a section titled "Installing Xcode Documentation" which says:

> Un-tar it and place it in the Shared Documentation folder:
>
> tar -xf ~/Downloads/AudioKit.tgz -C /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/

Probably I've missed something, but this seems incomplete and/or out of date. I have two questions:

1. Where do I download the "AudioKit.tgz" file?
2. Xcode Help for Xcode 9.1 says documentation should go in ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets. Which is correct?

Comment: I'll take a look at our downloads and see if something is missing or whatever needs to be done to modernize these instructions, thanks.